# How to get the Paypal IPN to capture Cancelled purchase to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, paypal-ipn

What I am trying to do is get the payment_status in my database, to update to the word "Cancelled" when the visitor clicks on the cancel button to return to my website.

What I have, is a perfectly working IPN script with pages that work flawlessly when a purchase is completed. The database is filled out and my PHP page will display the details of the purchase (for my viewing only). I am seeking some help to alter this to say when it is cancelled as well.

Note: I got this online from somewhere (I don't remember where) and all I had to do was change my mysql connection information. Any help is appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
    <?php
    // CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
    // Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
    // Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
    define("DEBUG", 0);
    // Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
    define("USE_SANDBOX", 0);
    define("LOG_FILE", "ipn.log");
    // Read POST data
    // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
    // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2)
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    // Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
    // Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
    if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    } else {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }
    $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
    if ($ch == FALSE) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    }
    // CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
    // CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
    // of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
    // This is mandatory for some environments.
    //$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
        {
        if(DEBUG == true) { 
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    } else {
            // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
    }
    // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
    // Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
    $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
    $res = trim(end($tokens));
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
        
        include("DBController.php");
        $db = new DBController();
        
        // check whether the payment_status is Completed
        $isPaymentCompleted = false;
        if($payment_status == "Completed") {
            $isPaymentCompleted = true;
        }
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        $isUniqueTxnId = false; 
        $param_type="s";
        $param_value_array = array($txn_id);
        $result = $db->runQuery("SELECT * FROM payment WHERE txn_id = ?",$param_type,$param_value_array);
        if(empty($result)) {
            $isUniqueTxnId = true;
        }   
        // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        if($isPaymentCompleted) {
            // $param_type = "sssdss";
            // $param_value_array = array($item_number, $item_name, $payment_status, $payment_amount, $payment_currency, $txn_id);
            // $payment_id = $db->insert("INSERT INTO payment(item_number, item_name, payment_status, payment_amount, payment_currency, txn_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", $param_type, $param_value_array);
            // error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Vdddddddddddderified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    
    
            $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', ' ', ' ', ' ');
            // Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
    
            $sql = "UPDATE nametable SET item_number='".$item_number."', item_name='".$item_name."', payment_status='".$payment_status."', payment_amount=".$payment_amount.", payment_currency='".$payment_currency."', txn_id='".$txn_id."' order by id DESC limit 1";
    
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "Record updated successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        } 
        // process payment and mark item as paid.
        
        
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation
        // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this myself by using a session to wrap around the functionality.
I hope this helps anyone that comes across this question

Answer (score 0):

IPN is for payment-impacting events, such as a new transaction, a refund, or a dispute.

A user choosing not to pay and "cancelling" their checkout, is not an IPN event. No IPN message will be sent to the IPN listener.

If a `cancel_return` [variable](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/) was specified when redirecting the payer from your site to PayPal, that is where they'll return to. You can have that URL do something. It won't have anything to do with your IPN url, but you can reuse some of the same mysql code if you need to do a similar operation.

Comment: Okay so the redirect I have specified on the paypal donation button, if they cancel, I can add something in that page to update the database. I don't think there is a way to capture that ID of the first entry to update it though once they get to the paypal site, and sent back to the cancelled page

Comment: do you know of a way to get the original mysql ID from the database entry, to pass to the redirected "cancel" page that I have specified in my donation button on paypal?

Answer (score -1):

The IPN sample you using is outdated. There is a need to confirm the receipt of the IPN to PayPal (otherwise it keeps resending it for a few days, you can check at the PayPal account IPN messages tab).

I just started to play around with IPN for a project, never used it before, maybe I am wrong, but my logic is:

1. Paypal sends the IPN.
2. Receive and verify. (Personally, I do not respond if the verification fails, as I believe if the message is from PayPal it should be valid).
3. Confirm IPN receipt.

I use the response if everything is okay, I mean verified.
So the code I use looks like this, and two lines should be added to yours:

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope this will be fine now.

Comment: Nice edit. Thanks for considering my feedback.

Comment: Welcome. I believe we all live by the feedback. I understand the OP's struggle and frustration, and as I stated it is maybe a little bit off-topic, but I believe it is important. I started to research how the IPN works, and most of the searches led to 5-8 years old samples and examples. Even the GitHub IPN listener is not updated just in the comments to remove the get_magic_quotes... Thanks for the feedback anyway.